# OpenGL + SDL Linking Problem

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

So I'm trying to write a simple application with SDL 1.2 and OpenGL. This a stripped down version of the code containing the one problem I'm having.

```
//The headers
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_opengl.h"

//Screen attributes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

//Event handler
SDL_Event event;

bool initGL()
{
    //Initialize Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Initialize Modelview Matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Initialize clear color
    glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

    //Check for error
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString( error ) );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool init()
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Create Window
    if( SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_OPENGL ) == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Enable unicode
    SDL_EnableUNICODE( SDL_TRUE );

    //Initialize OpenGL
    if( initGL() == false )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Set caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL );

    return true;
}

void render()
{
    //Clear color buffer
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f, -0.5f );
        glVertex2f(  0.5f,  0.5f );
        glVertex2f( -0.5f,  0.5f );
    glEnd();

    //Update screen
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}

void clean_up()
{
    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    //Quit flag
    bool quit = false;

    //Initialize
    if( init() == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Wait for user exit
    while( quit == false )
    {
        //While there are events to handle
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                quit = true;
            }
            else if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                //Handle keypress with current mouse position
                int x = 0, y = 0;
                SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y );
            }
        }

        //Render frame
        render();
    }

    //Clean up
    clean_up();

    return 0;
}
```

Anyway the code has a problem with `gluErrorString()` and reports:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gluErrorString@4 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)

1>C:\...\Debug\sdl1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express. I'm using SDL 1.2.15 and freeglut. I've added to the VC++ Directories both the SDL and freeglut library and include directories respectively and in the Linker general dependencies have added SDL.lib, SDLmain.lib, OpenGL32.lib, and freeglut.lib. And SDL.dll and freeglut.dll are included with the executable.

What's really baffling me is I can run SDL code with this same set up as well as OpenGL (if I include gl/glu.h and gl/gl.h manually), but trying to run them together has brought me to a screeching halt. If I comment out the line `printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString( error ) );` it works fine, but I have no idea why it can't seem to work with a simple thing like `gluErrorString()`, especially because `gluErrorString()` works fine in my OpenGL only code.

From what I understand `#include "SDL_opengl.h"` is supposed to include the opengl headers for me, and it seems to work for all but this one line, which I don't understand. If there's any further pertinent information needed I will provide it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since this question is primarily about coding that's not specific to gamedev, I've voted to close it as off topic. Questions that are not specific to game dev should be asked at stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers provide (among other things) function declarations and type definitions into the source files which you include them.
Libraries you link provide the symbols representing the definitions for those function declarations.

If you're missing an include, you're going to get a *compiler* error about an unknown identifier, type or function.

If you're missing a library or forgot to define a function you declared yourself, you're going to get a *linker* error about a missing symbol.

As your error is about a missing symbol for `gluErrorString`, you need to link `glu32.lib`, which is the OpenGL utility library.

For almost anything provided by a Microsoft-supplied library, you can find out which header to include and what library to link by reading the [MSDN page for the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Understood. I was able to fix the problem. Thanks for your help.